# Analyze php code regarding non-escaped queries etc

Tags: php

I wonder, if a solution exists, which statically analyzes PHP source-files.

I'm aware of [PHPLint](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/) and some other solution, which e.g. check code style.

My interest is more general: I'd like to **analyze web-specific problem, e.g. non-escaped queries** and such.

Does such an - probably conceptually incomplete - solution exist?

Comment: I'd imagine something like that would be rather difficult to implement, assuming it's even possible at all.  It would be a useful tool to be sure, but if you use prepared statements throughout your code then unescaped SQL injection attacks become very hard to pull off anyway.

Comment: That would be a blacklist scanner, as it's near impossible to differentiate SQL command from value concatenations. Conceptually even magic_quotes would be more reliable.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that such a solution would be non trivial and incomplete...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is of use to you? [RIPS – A static source code analyser for vulnerabilities in PHP scripts](http://www.php-security.org/2010/05/24/mops-submission-09-rips-a-static-source-code-analyser-for-vulnerabilities-in-php-scripts/index.html)

Comment: This one looks promising. Thank you!